# How do I extract the first word in a list within a dataframe object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

[View of abilities list / dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBtjU.png)
I would like to print the first skill in the abilities list for the first 10 rows. I have the first 10 rows, and have tried indexing the list with .str but I am having trouble. Thank you so much for your help.

df.loc[0:10]['Abilities']

OUTPUT:

0                  Overgrow,Chlorophyll
1                  Overgrow,Chlorophyll
2                  Overgrow,Chlorophyll
3                                Sturdy
4                     Blaze,Solar Power
5                     Blaze,Solar Power
6                     Blaze,Solar Power
7     Sand Force,Sheer Force,Intimidate
8            Water Compaction,Sand Veil
9                     Torrent,Rain Dish
10                    Torrent,Rain Dish
Name: Abilities, dtype: object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the most efficient/designed-for way but:

`first_item_list = [df.loc[0:10]['Abilities'].values[i].split(',')[0] for i in range(10)]`

seems to be doing the job!